# Is active vocabulary increasing, decreasing or stays approximately the same?

Tags: vocabulary

English constantly borrows or makes up new words. At the same time, other words become old-fashioned and obsolete. Do the two processes balance each other and the language's active vocabulary (words which are more or less commonly used) is neither getting bigger nor shrinking? Or one process prevails over the other?

Comment: There isn't a big vocabulary bin in the sky with a counter on it. Everybody has their own vocabulary, and it's different from everybody else's. How old one is and how much one reads and talks and listens, and who one reads and talks to and listens to, has a lot to do with vocabulary size. The older you get, the more you've learned, but the more you forget. Younger people have the new words. But pretty much, we have words for whatever we need, and nobody's counting. (Seriously, nobody's counting; it's impossible)

Comment: The larger the cloud gets, the more word definitions it can store.